# Plural or singular in permission description

Tags: grammatical-number

We have a product where users can be given permissions to perform certain actions.
Part of our data consists of lists of items. A user with the relevant permission can replace items in lists by other items, but only one at a time.

Should this permission be named:
"Replace an item in a list" or "Replace items in lists"?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Requests to rephrase single sentences, phrases, or words are off-topic but acceptable on English SE. I'll ask the mods if this can be migrated.

Answer (score 1):

The permission should be "Edit lists".

The item is not needed because it is implied.  If you have several lists that can be edited that have different categories (say you have a set of lists for products, a set of list for emails, a set of lists for stores), then modify/add permission labels to those specific categories.

If you want separate permission sets for the lists such as:

Edit product lists

Edit store lists

Edit E-mail lists

you can label them out specific to the permission of the lists you want.

but if this permission gives users global access to all lists to edit items,  then a simple edit lists would suffice.

Comment: Thanks, but I oversimplified. The permission is specific to replacing items in the list, and doesn't cover other ways to edit lists. My question is really if singular or plural forms of the words should be used.

Comment: you want to add the element of singular with the possibility of multiple so something like:  "Replace one or more items in a list".  They are only replacing items in 1 list at a time, but they have the option to replace multiple items in 1 list.

Comment: Right, but trying to keep it shorter than that.

Comment: If we were to assume all types of editing were allowed, but one could only edit a single list at any given time, would the permission be "Edit lists", or "Edit a list"?

Comment: it would still be edit lists because they are able to edit multiple lists, even if it is one at a time.  If you say edit list, the user will wonder which list?  the manager or who ever is the one with the ability to set such permissions may be confused as well and wonder what list exactly is able to be edited as it is implied singular rather than multiple.  Edit lists now implies that they have the ability to edit multiple lists and since there is no specification to what kind of lists, the user can further imply any list on the site can be edited by them.

Comment: If you want to do "replace an item in a list" the same issue would arise.  The user would think that A) they can only edit 1 item at a time in a list and not multiple, and that B) they can only edit 1 list and they may be confused without further clarification.  The issue with software instruction/labels is that, you have to write without assuming the user has knowledge of what you mean.  If you walk up to someone and say great! you now have the ability to edit an item in a list.. they are going to say ok... which list can i edit? and you would have to clarify all.

Comment: if you walk up to someone and say, great you can now edit the lists.  They will know that they have the ability to edit all the lists because it implies multiple.

Comment: Thanks. What you are saying is pretty much what I said to our technical writer, who is insistent on using singular forms. I wanted to get another opinion without showing my own.

Comment: Yea, being a developer myself, I understand that conflict.  The problem is, too many times software instructions, or text that the user would read is written from the technical point of view, the developer's point of view with their way of thinking.  Users though don't think like we do, nor do they interpret the instructions the way we do because we have knowledge and understanding they don't with the software.  So without explicit instructions or descriptions, things need to be written a way that if you were to ask someone, they wouldn't need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think renaming the permission as "**Replacing item(s) in lists**" would be self-explanatory and serve the purpose.

Hope it helps!